# Calculating volume enclosed using triple integral

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume, faq

> Calculate the volume enclosed between $x^2 + y^2=1$, $y^2+z^2=1$, $x^2+z^2=1$

I am supposed to solve this question using multiple integral. I am not able to visualize the resultant figure of whose I am supposed to calculate the volume.

Comment: Three cylinders intersection. Visualizing is indeed a bit hard, see  http://www.mathmos.net/puzzles/intersect1.png

Comment: This post is chosen to be the target/mother for [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) because it has an existing link while others have none.

Comment: With three circle equations being the same as a sphere and with a radius of one, we have  $$V=\frac{4\pi}{3}\approx 4.19$$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\mbox{Note that}\quad
V \equiv \iiint_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}\Theta\pars{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}
\Theta\pars{1 - y^{2} - z^{2}}\Theta\pars{1 - z^{2} - x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
$$
which we'll evaluate in cylindrical coordinates:
$\ds{x = \rho\cos\pars{\phi}}$, $\ds{y = \rho\sin\pars{\phi}}$ and $\ds{z = z}$ with $\ds{\rho \geq 0}$ and $\ds{0 \leq \phi < 2\pi}$.

> \begin{align}
> V&=\iiint_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}\Theta\pars{1 - \rho^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{1 - \rho^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi} - z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{1 - z^{2} - \rho^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd z\int_{0}^{2\pi}
> \Theta\pars{1 - \rho\sin^{2}\pars{\phi} - z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi} - z^{2}}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd z\int_{0}^{\pi}
> \Theta\pars{1 - \rho\sin^{2}\pars{\phi} - z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi} - z^{2}}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\phi\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{\root{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}} - z}
> \Theta\pars{\root{1 - \rho\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}} - z}\,\dd z
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
V&=4\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\root{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi
+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\root{1 - \rho\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi}
\\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\root{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi
+\int_{-\pi/4}^{0}\root{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi}
\\[3mm]&=8\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dd\phi\int_{0}^{1}
\root{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\rho
=8\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dd\phi\
\braces{{2\bracks{1 - \rho\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}^{3/2} \over -3\cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}}
_{\rho\ =\ 0}^{\rho\ =\ 1}
\\[3mm]&={16 \over 3}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\bracks{1 - \sin^{3}\pars{\phi} \over \cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi
={16 \over 3}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\bracks{\sec^{2}\pars{\phi} - {1 - \cos^{2}\pars{\phi} \over \cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\,\sin\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi
\\[3mm]&={16 \over 3}
\bracks{1 +\ \underbrace{\int_{1}^{\root{2}/2}{1 - t^{2} \over t^{2}}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{2 - {3 \over 2}\,\root{2}}}}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#66f}{\Large V = 8\pars{2 - \root{2}}} \approx {\tt 4.6863}
\end{align}

Comment: +4 from me. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks. I like integration 'without pictures'.

Comment: Anyway, what is $\Theta$? I don't get it each step in the grey area. Could please elaborate Felix? Sorry, I am not good at this stuff.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey $\Theta\left(\,x\,\right)$ is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):
$$
\Theta\left(\,x\,\right)\equiv
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & x < 0
\\&&
\\
1 & \mbox{if} & x > 0
\end{array}\right.
$$
It's quite useful whenever you don't want to deal with pictures.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey In the gray area:
The first line just set the boundary with the help of the $\Theta$ function. In the second line I did the map $\rho^{2}\mapsto \rho$ and integrate $z$ over $\left(0,\infty\right)$ because it's an even function of $z$. In the third and fourth lines, I manipulated the $\phi$-integration to move everything to $\left(0,\pi/2\right)$. Also, I integrate $\rho$ over $\left(0,1\right)$ because the factor $\Theta\left(1 - \rho\right)$ limits the integration to $\left(0,1\right)$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Don't feel sorry. You can ask many times as you like. Thanks.

Comment: OK, give me time to learn your explanation. If I have a question, I'll ask you again. Thank you so much for your detail explanations. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @FelixMarin Can you please help me over here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341174/how-to-find-the-volume-enclosed-by-intersection-of-three-orthogonal-cylinders

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the three cylinders is a "curvilinear polyhedron" with $14$ vertices: $8$ vertices of the type (i)
$$\left(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
that simultaneously belong to the boundaries of all the three cylinders, and $6$ vertices of the type (ii)
$$\left(\pm 1,0,0\right)\quad \left(0,\pm 1,0\right)\quad \left(0,0,\pm 1\right)$$
that belong to the boundaries of just two cylinders. By symmetry, the volume is given by the volume of the cube that is the convex envelope of type-(i) points, $2\sqrt{2}$, plus $6$ times the volume of the apse that lies above the face with vertices in
$$\left(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$
We may compute the volume of such an apse through Cavalieri's principle. The intersection between the apse and the plane $y=k\in[1/\sqrt{2},1]$ is a square with vertices in
$$\left(\pm\sqrt{1-k^2},k,\pm\sqrt{1-k^2}\right),$$
hence its area is just $4(1-k^2)$ and the volume of the apse is:
$$4\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}(1-k^2)\,dk = \frac{1}{3}(8-5\sqrt{2}), $$
so the volume of the intersection of the three cylinders is:

> $$ V = 8 (2-\sqrt{2}). $$

Answer (score 1):

No need to use trig or to integrate things more complicated than 1, $x$, or $x^2$.

First we separate the volume into octants based on the signs of $x$, $y$, $z$, each octant giving 1/8 of the total volume. Then we consider that the variables can be ordered by size in 6 ways, so we can assume $x>y>z$ and get 1/6 of the volume of an octant or 1/48 of the total volume $V$. Thus $x$ goes from 0 to 1, $y$ goes maximally to either $x$ (because in our sector $x>y$) or $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (which is the border of the object). $z$ alway goes from 0 to $y$ because the other inequalities $x^2+z^2<1$ and $y^2+z^2<1$ are satisfied automatically by having sorted the variables.

The integral to work on is then

$$w=\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{{\rm min}(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})} \int_{z=0}^y 1\ dz\,dy\,dx $$

The innermost integral is $y$, the second goes from 0 to either $x$ if $x<\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ or to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ otherwise (where I solved the trivial integral along $y$). We split the integral in a sum of the two cases:

$$w_1=\int_{x=0}^{2/\sqrt2} \frac{x^2}{2} dx = \frac{\sqrt2}{24} $$

$$w_2=\int_{x=2/\sqrt2}^1 \frac{1-x^2}{2} dx = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{5\sqrt2}{24}$$

$$w = w_1+w_2 = \frac13 - \frac{\sqrt2}{6}$$

Therefore $V = 48 w = 16-8\sqrt2 $

That's 1.11877 times the volume of the enclosed sphere, which sounds plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Those are 3 cylinders that intersect, try to sketch it, and then use the symmetry of the cylinders and calculate just the part of the volume that satisfies $x,y,z\geq 0$

Comment: Why only for $x,y,z\geq 0$?

Comment: The volume is symmetric, so you could just calculate that and multiply by 8.

Comment: Oh! I thought you were suggesting to calculate only that. As per the link given by @ganeshie8, three cylinder intersection would look like-http://www.mathmos.net/puzzles/intersect1.png. I am still finding it tough.

Comment: Can you explain why the volume just turns out to be $8(2-\sqrt{2})$? Even exploiting symmetry, the resulting integral is non-trivial.