# Volume inside 3 cylinders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region lying inside all three of the 
circular cylinders $$x^2+y^2=a^2,$$ $$x^2+z^2=a^2,$$ $$y^2+z^2=a^2$$
Hint: Make a good sketch of the first octant 
part of the region, and use symmetry whenever possible.

I have trouble in identifying the function to integrate and the boundary of the integral. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The integrand is $1$ and the domain is the intersection of the inside of the cylinders.

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508), which merit is not in the content nor being the oldest but merely having an existing link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[3 CYL INTRXN](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/cylinders/)

Google for images of intersection of cylinders, above site is one useful.

First obtain intersection area/volume of two cylinders as practice , before going to the more general three mutually perpendicular tubes case. I could build a 3D model in steel. It has cut portions of sine curve at endpoints. Deciding start and end points in one octant is central task here.

EDIT1: With two cylinder intersection the plane of intersection is $ x=y $. Now choose a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Your shadow in xy plane is x^2+y^2=a^2 chop in up into 8 parts say take a piece from theta varying 0 to pi/4 .See which cylinder u hit when drawing a ray upwards . u can do this by seeing which i down and which is up by plugging in some value in( y less than x) .