# Volume of a solid formed by 3 cylinders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I am trying to find the volume of the solid enclosed by three cylinders given by $x^2+y^2=1$, $x^2+z^2=1$, and $y^2+z^2=1$. I'm supposed to be using a triple integral, and I assume, cylindrical coordinates.

So far, I've figured out that I need to evaluate a triple integral of $dV$, which is equal to $rdzdrd\theta$. However, I am having trouble figuring out what bounds to use for $r, \theta, z$.

Any assistance or hints with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a good source on [Steinmetz Solids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html) to act as supplementary material to the answer below. When you're solving problems like this, graphing and drawing detailed pictures can be very helpful in visualizing the boundaries of the solid.

Comment: @B.Standage: interesting, I did not know such a solid had a name ! drawing is always helpful, but in 3D can be many times also misleading, so I personally found by experience that inequalities set are **unavoidable**

Comment: I agree, sometimes it can get a little messy. If you're interested, here's another [source](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_summer_06/handouts/3cylinder.pdf) that gives a few good drawings of this shape. It also adds a visual aid to the below solution as their methods are almost identical.

Comment: @B.Standage: thanks, it is helpful.

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508), which merit is not in the content nor being the oldest but merely having an existing link.

Answer (score 4):

Take the cylinders as **solid**, so $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ and so on.

Take for symmetry the first octant, i.e. $0 \le x,y,z$.

Then change the coordinates to cylindrical to obtain
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le r\,(by\,def.) \hfill \cr 
  0 \le r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ,z \hfill \cr 
  r^2 \left( {\cos ^2 \theta  + \sin ^2 \theta } \right) \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  z^2  + r^2 \cos ^2 \theta  \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  z^2  + r^2 \sin ^2 \theta  \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

and simplify to
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le \theta  \le \pi /2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le r \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le z \le \sqrt {1 - r^2 \cos ^2 \theta }  \hfill \cr 
  0 \le z \le \sqrt {1 - r^2 \sin ^2 \theta }  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

To solve for the last two bounds in $z$, again using symmetry,
just reduce the angle to $\pi /4$, and integrate with these conditions
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le \theta  \le \pi /4 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le r \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le z \le \sqrt {1 - r^2 \cos ^2 \theta }  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Then finally you shall multiply by $16$.

Comment: Thank you! So, just to clarify, the integral is multiplied by 16 because we were looking at an 8th of the solid and then cut that in half by reducing the angle further?

Comment: @C.Thomson: Yes, exactly because that.

Comment: @C.Thomson: sorry, I made an error in the last set: for $0 \le \theta \le \pi /4$ the "leading" inequality is that in $cos$, not in $sin$. I have amended my answer accordingly.