# Find the volume of intersection between cylinders

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, cylindrical-coordinates

> Find the volume of intersection of the cylinder
>    {$ x^2 + 
> y^2 \leq 1 $} , {$ x^2 + z^2 \leq 1$}, {$ y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$}.

i am having tough time finding the volume how do i solve this kind of questions ? .

my trial :
i will move to the cylinder coordinates of the xy cylinder let :

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $

$ z = z $

$0\leq\theta \leq 2\pi$

solving the inequalties i get :

$ 0 \leq r^2 \leq 1$

$ -\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{2}}\leq z \leq \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{2}}$

$0\leq\theta \leq 2\pi$

the integral is :

$ \int_{z=-\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{2}}}^{z=\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{2}}}\int_{r=0}^{r=1}\int_0^{2\pi} dz \ dr \ d{\theta}$ = $ \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{(2-r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{-3} |_{r=0}^{r=1}$

Comment: What does your integral look like? If you show your attempted solution you are more likely to get useful feedback.

Comment: i'll write that in a moment.

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: I'm not sure about your bounds for $z$, how exactly did you get those?

Comment: Either way it looks like you're missing the Jacobian, which is $r$ for cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: no the jacobian is already calculated , also i found z by adding the last 2 inequalities

Comment: $ x^2 + z^2 \leq 1 ,\ y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ adding : $ x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 \leq 2$ or $ r^2 + 2z^2 \leq 2$

Comment: see mathworld's entry on  [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html)

Comment: hey can you explain what is wrong with my answer since the number is slightly bigger in my answer

Comment: The upper and lower bound of your $z$ integral should be $\pm \sqrt{1 - r^2\max(\cos^2\theta,\sin^2\theta)}$, not $\pm \sqrt{ 1 - r^2/2}$

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508), which merit is not in the content nor being the oldest but merely having an existing link.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, it is not necessary to use polar coordinates, nor even multiple integration or trigonometry, to find the volume.

What we need to do is consider the volume of a solid whose cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are rectangles whose width is $x$ and whose height is $\sqrt{1-x^2} - 1/\sqrt{2}$, over the interval $x \in [0,1/\sqrt{2}]$.  This is simply $$\int_{x=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} x \left(\sqrt{1 - x^2} - 1/\sqrt{2}\right) \, dx = \left[-\frac{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]_{x=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} = \frac{8 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{24}.$$  Then the desired volume is $48$ times this volume, plus the volume of the inscribed cube, which gives $$2\sqrt{2} + 2(8-5\sqrt{2}) = 8(2 - \sqrt{2}).$$  I have left the reasoning as an exercise for the reader.

An alternative computation can be set up that includes the inscribed cube in the integral, simply by changing the height of the perpendicular cross section to $\sqrt{1-x^2} - x$, giving $$\frac{V}{48} = \int_{x=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} x \left(\sqrt{1-x^2} - x\right) \, dx.$$  Again, the details are left for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$V = 16 \int\limits_0^{\pi/4} \int\limits_0^1 s \sqrt{1 - s^2 \cos^2 \theta}\ ds\ d\theta = 8(2 - \sqrt{2}) $$

Comment: hey can you explain what is wrong with my answer since the number is slightly bigger