# Question regarding the volume integral of a 3D solid.

Tags: volume, multiple-integral

$\mathbf {The \ Problem}$: Find the volume of the solid in $3D$ enclosed by the three cylinders with their equations given below,

$$x^2+y^2 =1,$$

$$ y^2+z^2 =1, $$

$$ z^2+x^2 =1 .$$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}$: Actually, I tried to figure it out using the polar coordinates. Here, $0\leq r\leq 1$ and

$$z = \min (1-r^2\operatorname{sin^2\theta}, 1-r^2\operatorname{cos^2\theta} ).$$

Hence the volume is

$$V = 4 \left( \int_0^{π/4} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta} rdrd{\theta} + 
\int_{π/4}^{π/2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\theta} rdrd{\theta} \right)$$

then the answer is found to be $8/(3\sqrt{2})$ .

Comment: there was an exact same question a few hours ago, and apparently this link helped that user https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508/calculating-volume-enclosed-using-triple-integral Also, I guess part of the problem is that you're missing a whole bunch on square-roots.

Comment: This region has more symmetry of which you can take advantage and get a very simple integral. In fact, the problem can be solved, using the way Archimedes would have, without using calculus at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Sir, can you please explain me about Archimedes's solution or provide me a link ???

Comment: Take a look at pages 2-9 of [a lecture I gave some years ago](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/MAA.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your volume integral is fine, except for an overall factor of 8 instead of 4.

The integral below is expressed in $xy$-coordinates in the first quadrant, for $z > 0$. The factor 8 accounts for 8 identical integral contributions to the total volume.

$$V = 8 \int_0^{π/4} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta} rdrd{\theta} + 
8\int_{π/4}^{π/2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\theta} rdrd{\theta} $$

The two integrals in the above expression are actually the same in value due to symmetry between sine and cosine.

Thus,

$$V= 16 \int_0^{π/4} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta} rdrd{\theta} = 8(2-\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: Sir, how can you tell that the result in the link is incorrect ???

Comment: Double checked the last step, which is actually equivalent to the last couple of lines of the link. So, your integral gives the same result. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have three equations of circles which is the same as one equation for a sphere. [Here](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-formulas/derivation-formula-volume-sphere-integration) is a link showing the integration steps needed to find it. In your case, with a radius of $1$, the formula $\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$ reduces to 
$$V=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$